# jQuery submenu position bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I`m trying to create menu which is opening on clicking parent element and closeing on mouseleave from that one which was opened a while ago. It should work from left to right

Here is

```
    <ul class="menuFirst">
        <li><img src="img/ico1.png"></li>
            <ul class="">
                <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submoduł1"></li>
                <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submoduł2"></li>
                <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submoduł3"></li>
            </ul>
        <li><img src="img/ico1.png"></li>
            <ul class="menuSecond">
                <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submoduł1"></li>
                <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submoduł2"></li>
                <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submoduł3"></li>
            </ul>
        <li><img src="img/ico1.png"></li>
            <ul class="menuSecond">
                <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submoduł1"></li>
                <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submoduł2"></li>
                <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submoduł3"></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
```

Here is CSS

```
ul.menuFirst{
    list-style-type: none;
border-top: #AAA solid 3px;
border-right: #AAA solid 3px;
border-bottom: #AAA solid 2px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 70px;}
    ul.menuFirst li{
    background: #DDD;
    border-bottom: #AAA solid 1px;
}
ul.menuFirst li img{
margin:5px;
}
ul.menuFirst ul{
display: none;
}
    ul.menuFirst ul.menuSecond {
list-style: none;
display: table;
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
    }
    ul.menuFirst ul.menuSecond li{
display: table-cell;
    }
```

And here is jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.menuFirst li").click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();            
        var ypos= $(this).next().position();
        alert(ypos.top);
        $(this).next().css('top','-=38');

        $('ul.menuFirst ul.menuSecond').one('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).css('top', '+=38').toggle();
    });
    });
});
```

It works for 1st element but it's pretty buggy. When I'm trying to add .animate() It just didn't work. So I`ve decided to take step back and unbug this one but i don't know how. It should looks like this:
[image: Finished menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I`ve fix it....

```
    $('ul.menuFirst ul').each(function(){
        $(this).css('top', '-=38').hide();
    });
```

This is executing where DOM is ready I don't need to change position each time while I`m opening or closeing it.

```
        $("ul.menuFirst li").click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle("slide", 
                 {direction: "left"})
        });

        $('ul.menuFirst ul.menuSecond').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).hide("slide", 
                 {direction: "left"});
```

Nextly I`m ussing this to animate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not correct use this

```
<ul class="menuFirst">
    <li><img src="img/ico1.png">
        <ul class="">
            <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submodul1"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submodul2"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submodul3"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><img src="img/ico1.png">
        <ul class="menuSecond">
            <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submodul1"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submodul2"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submodul3"></li>
    </ul>
        </li>
    <li><img src="img/ico1.png">
        <ul class="menuSecond">
            <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submodul1"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submodul2"></li>
            <li><img src="img/ico2.png" alt="submodul3"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: @Sergio, `<li><img src="img/ico1.png"></li><ul>`